# Electron File Structure and Building An App

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I've recently learned about Electron and it seems like a nifty way to create desktop applications. I've created a simple Twitter Aggregator that works once I run `nodemon app.js` and I want to package it up with Atom to run in it's own window on my computer.

I understand that an electron app must have a package.json and a main.js file in the root directory to run electron. So for organizational purposes, I created a folder called /app where my twitter aggregator files live.

When I run `npm start` it launches electron and opens a browser window that loads my index.html file. However I have two issues:

1) It gives me an error in console - Reference Error: $ is undefined

2) How do get it to run /app/app.js (which is what uses the Twitter API on the backend)?

This is my github repo: https://github.com/OneHunnid/dimmiDesktopApp

Comment: It doesn't work as like that, Electron doesn't need express or something like that.
 I recommend you to see my electron app [Github](https://github.com/amovah/DiveTodo)

Comment: This should be two separate questions. But I tried to answer both.

Answer (score 1):

The error with `$ is undefined` is something that I ran into as well. The problem is with the `nodeintegration` features in the `BrowserWindow`. So, you can either turn `nodeintegration` off by passing `nodeintegration: false` with your options in your `BrowserWindow` constructor. OR you can add the following script tag in between the jquery script tag and your moment script tag on the `index.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(window && !window.$ && !window.jQuery && module && module.exports && module.exports){
      window.$ = window.jQuery = module.exports;
    }
</script>
```

This is caused because when jQuery bootstraps, it checks to see if it can detect a `module`. Normally in the browser you don't have one. So, if `module` exists, then jQuery attaches as `module.exports`. So, you just need to include this script that will set `window.$` and `window.jQuery` equal to `module.exports`, which is where jQuery bootstrapped to.

That should fix your first issues.

As for your second issues, you should put the following in your index.html to make it work.

```
<script src="app.js"></script> //if not app.js, app/app.js
```

Let me know if this helps.